# Flask - jinja2 access data from filtered result

Tags: python, jinja2

data:

```
[
            {
                "name": "fixed",
                "addr": "172.16.1.100",
                "active": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "name": "floating",
                "addr": "10.90.80.10",
                "active": "No"
            }
        ]
```

i am trying to filter this data in the jinja2 template and value from the filtered result.

```
{{ data|selectattr("name", "equalto", "floating")}}
```

this gives me

```
{
                "name": "floating",
                "addr": "10.90.80.10",
                "active": "No"
            }
```

i would like to get the active status from this result.
i tried `{{ data|selectattr("name", "equalto", "floating")|attr("active")}}` and it returns as blank.

what is the right way to do this? to access the attribute after applying a jinja filter "|"

Note: I just tried below and it works. The problem is when i apply filter and then i try to access an attribute. using the attr menthod.

```
This works
{{ data[0]['active'] }}

This doesnt 
{{ data|first|attr('active') }}
```

Comment: You are missing comma after the `addr` attribute value.

Comment: updated the question. the above was just sample data. so the problem is not with the data.

Answer (score 2):

try this if you want to filter active status too

```
{{ data|selectattr("name", "equalto", "floating")|selectattr("active", "equalto", "No")|list }}
```

that's what I catch from your question, I didn't know what do you really want with "active" filter.

**Edited:**

if you just wanna get value from active just simply do this:

```
{{ (data|selectattr("name", "equalto", "floating")|list)[0]["active"] }}
```

Comment: thats not what i wanted. what i wanted was to access the value using the key. In pythonic way "data.get(''active")". I am not able to get this to work when i use a filter(in this case selectattr-equalto). the want to apply the get method on the result of the filter.

Comment: as a temporary solution i am using {% set tempdata= data|selectattr("name", "equalto", "floating") %} and then {{ tempdata['active'] }}. this works. is there way to make this work in one line?